# Existence of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at a point

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given the following function
\begin{align*}
    g: \mathbb{R}&\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\\
    x&\mapsto \begin{cases}
    x   &\mbox{, $-\pi<x<\pi$}\\
    0&\mbox{, $x=-\pi$}\\
    g(x+2\pi)=g(x)&\mbox{for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,}
              \end{cases}             
\end{align*}

The Fourier series of the function in the point 3. diverges at 0 but I don't the conditions,also I don't knwo how to prove the  points 1 and 2

1.Show that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
    |S_{n}(g,t)|\leq \pi+2,
\end{align*}
where $S_{n}$ defines the Nth partial sum of the Fourier Series.

2.It is defined for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$
\begin{align*}
    \varphi_{n}:\mathbb{R}&\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\\
    x&\mapsto\frac{1}{\pi+2}e^{int}S_{n}(g,x)
\end{align*}
Show that there exists $K>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$
\begin{align*}
    |S_{n}(\varphi_{n},0)|>K \ln{n}.
\end{align*}

3. What condition must satisfy the positive integers $n_{j}$ and $\lambda_{j}$ so that the Fourier series of the function

\begin{align*}
  f:\mathbb{R}&\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\\
  x&\mapsto\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}}e^{i\lambda_{j}x}\varphi_{n_{j}}(x)
\end{align*}
diverge for $t=0$ and converges for all $t\in[-\pi,0)\cup(0,\pi]$.

Comment: No, first I want to prove Nth partial sum of that  Fourier Series is bounded by $\pi+2$

Comment: I corrected the question sorry. The series that a I want to prove that diverges at zero is the series in the point 3.